# Deep Packet Inspection Switch in a Software Defined Network with OpenFlow Protocol

Tags: networking, network-protocols, openflow

I am trying to figure out whether or not Deep Packet Inspection switches are used in Software Defined Networks using OpenFlow protocol?  I know that Deep Packet Inspection switches have been developed as I found one company up in Canada who produces them but could not find if they work in a SDN environment using OpenFlow.  Any help would be appreciated, if you have any references it would be very nice to be able to read more up on it.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think DPI in SDN environments is mostly used in scenarios where all flows matching some tuple is sent through a DPI box. SDN is more about flow control and traffic engineering than these type of services.

However, you could do DPI using OpenFlow where all traffic were encapsulated (Packet_in, Packet_out) and sent to the controller (with some DPI application) for inspection. This would however not be practical because of the latency connected with the traverse time from device to controller and back again.

I would, in an SDN environment, look on DPI "switches" as a black box you send traffic through for inspection. And not a part of the forwarding mesh.

Comment: @John please confirm the answer if you find it acceptable